# Jumping between opening and closing bracket in texstudio

Tags: math-mode, texstudio

Coming from vim, if you place your cursor on the opening/closing bracket (block in vim speak) you can hit the % character to jump back and forth between the opening/closing bracket.   Can we do the same in Texstudio?  This would help a lot if I wanted to update the size of the brackets (e.g. to `\Big`).  Or is there a similar command in TeXstudio that can perform the update action (i.e. changing `( some_text )` to `\Big( some_text \Big)` and vice versa) that you know of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jump between matching braces, parentheses and brackets using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> followed by <kbd>j</kbd> (all keys released before this last one). This seems to be a rough equivalent of Vim's <kbd>%</kbd> command.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve your goals. Depending on the situation different approaches can be reasonable.

**Jumping between brackets**

Simply jumping between brackets is possible using `Idefix -> Parentheses -> Jump to Match`. This is very generic, but you have to type the changes yourself.

**Search using regular expessions**

A simple way of replacing `( some_text )` with `\Big( some_text \Big)` would be to use Search/Replace with regular expressions. E.g.
[image]

This comes in handy if you have to do a lot of replacements at a time. The disadvantage is that regular expressions cannot reasonably describe parentheses matching. I.e. it will fail if you have nested parentheses.

**Use as Script Macro**

Another approach would be to create a script macro (`Maros -> Edit Macros...`). Here's a basic example:

```
%SCRIPT
app.getManagedAction('main/edit2/parens/selectBracketInner').trigger()
text = cursor.selectedText()
app.getManagedAction('main/edit2/parens/selectBracketOuter').trigger()
newtext = '\\Big(' + text + '\\Big)'
cursor.replaceSelectedText(newtext)
cursor.clearSelection()
```

After creating the macro, you can change its shortcut at `Options -> Shortcuts`.

Comment: Thanks Tim, kudos for giving 3 options to solve the problem.  Really appreciate that.